# SQL oracle where date field = Last Friday

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a where clause with a date field, I want it to find the latest Friday when this auto runs every Monday or Tuesday of the following week.

Currently:

```
WHERE b.CALENDAR_DATE = To_Date('2020-08-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I want to find the latest Friday

Comment: I *think* `TO_DATE` is an Oracle function but please update your question with the correct dbms tag

Comment: Seems that you are using Oracle, I think you can do: WHERE b.CALENDAR_DATE = next_day (sysdate-7,'FRIDAY')

Comment: Thanks iceblade, I got it to work using "next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'FRIDAY') - 7"

Comment: That  gives the wrong date if you run it on a Friday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRUNC( date_value, 'IW' )` (which is language independent) to truncate to the start of the ISO week, which is always a Monday, and then subtract 3 days. You will also want to add 2 days before truncating so that the filter is correct if `SYSDATE` is a Saturday or Sunday.

```sql
WHERE b.CALENDAR_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '2' DAY, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '3' DAY
AND   b.CALENDAR_DATE <  TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '2' DAY, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '2' DAY
```

*(Note: dates can have a non-zero time component so if you want all dates on the last Friday then you will need a range of values rather than just comparing to last Friday at midnight.)*

Or you can use `NEXT_DAY( date_value - INTERVAL '8' DAY, 'FRIDAY' )` (which is language dependent):

```sql
WHERE b.CALENDAR_DATE >= NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '8' DAY, 'FRIDAY' )
AND   b.CALENDAR_DATE <  NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '8' DAY, 'FRIDAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ae563229ebd8efea0de4ae7f24bd9b9)*